# get back sharedpreferences after delete and install app

Tags: android, save, backup, sharedpreferences

hi friend i am trying to make game and i need to create demo version of my game

i need a button that when users click  on it the game run but just 3 time.

after 3 time users clicked on button the app show message "you should buy the game"

i used sharedpreferences . after 3 click on button the game show  message but when user delete app and  install it again , game not show message and run game.

are there any ways to save sharedpreferences after delete app ?
this is my code :

```
     Button frist = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.test));
               final SharedPreferences check = getSharedPreferences("check",MODE_PRIVATE);
               final Editor edit = check.edit();
```

`frist.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if(check.getInt("check1",0)<3){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,choose_name.class
                    );
            startActivity(intent);
            edit.putInt("check1", check.getInt("check1",0)+1).commit();


            }


        }
    });`

edit : friend im trying to write a file and save my setting into it , can i save my file in any directory that users cant see it and my file dont delete after user delete app and i dont need to use  permission?

Comment: no there is no way. SharedPreferences are deleted when you uninstall the application. The new version of inAppBilling allows you to offer a trial period

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if user uninstall/delete app or clean data through setting then all the data in shared preference will get vanished

your problem is when user do such kind of things with your application shared preference value get initialized from 0/starting value

you can use webservice for that for ex. you can take users IMEI number through code and against of that you can save its  sharedpreference value of " number of play counter"
and then through smart logic check your requirement

Android provides several options for you to save persistent application data. The solution you choose depends on your specific needs, such as whether the data should be private to your application or accessible to other applications (and the user) and how much space your data requires.

Your data storage options are the following:

Shared Preferences Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.

Internal Storage Store private data on the device memory.

External Storage Store public data on the shared external storage.

SQLite Databases Store structured data in a private database.

Network Connection Store data on the web with your own network server.

Android provides a way for you to expose even your private data to other applications — with a content provider. A content provider is an optional component that exposes read/write access to your application data, subject to whatever restrictions you want to impose. For more information about using content providers, see the Content Providers documentation.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: above link is use to demostrate connection of android data through webservices ( php) to server

Answer (score 4):

Try **[Backing up and restoring a user’s SharedPreferences](http://blog.grapefruitopia.com/post/18755719222/backing-up-and-restoring-a-users-sharedpreferences)**. This will backup your preference to any **External Storage**.

Before user uninstall app, you can take back up of it. Add some logic that if file is present in **External Storage**, restore it back.

**Edit**

Use following code to back your preference.

> Preferences stored in the SharedPreferences class get saved into /data/data//shared_prefs/_preferences.xml - backing up is easy, you just need to copy the contents of this file to external storage:

```
public static void backupUserPrefs(Context context) {
    final File prefsFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "../shared_prefs/" + context.getPackageName() + "_preferences.xml");
    final File backupFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null),
        "preferenceBackup.xml");
    String error = "";

    try {
        FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(prefsFile).getChannel();
        FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupFile).getChannel();

        dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());

        src.close();
        dst.close();

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Backed up user prefs to " + backupFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Use following code to restore preference

> But restoring provides more of a challenge, since the shared_prefs file isn’t directly writable by the app, and the SharedPrefs class doesn’t directly expose its functionality to serialise from xml. Instead you have to parse the XML yourself and push the values back in.  Thankfully the XML file has a straightforward structure, so it’s easy to loop over the elements and turn these back into preferences.

```
public static boolean restoreUserPrefs(Context context) {
    final File backupFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null),
        "preferenceBackup.xml");
    String error = "";

    try {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(backupFile);

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(inputStream);
        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

        Node child = root.getFirstChild();
        while (child != null) {
            if (child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element element = (Element) child;

                String type = element.getNodeName();
                String name = element.getAttribute("name");

                // In my app, all prefs seem to get serialized as either "string" or
                // "boolean" - this will need expanding if yours uses any other types!    
                if (type.equals("string")) {
                    String value = element.getTextContent();
                    editor.putString(name, value);
                } else if (type.equals("boolean")) {
                    String value = element.getAttribute("value");
                    editor.putBoolean(name, value.equals("true"));
                }
            }

            child = child.getNextSibling();

        }

        editor.commit();

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Restored user prefs from " + backupFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        return true;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to restore user prefs from " + backupFile.getAbsolutePath() + " - " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

    return false;
}


    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Back up user prefs to " + backupFile.getAbsolutePath() + " - " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

}
```

> Finally, you need to restart your app before these preferences will take hold:

```
if (restoreUserPrefs(context)) {
    // Restart              
    AlarmManager alm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(
    Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alm.set(AlarmManager.RTC,
    System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
    new Intent(context, MainActivityName.class), 0));
    android.os.Process.sendSignal(android.os.Process.myPid(),
    android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
}
```

Comment: in this way need to add permisson to my app ?

Comment: @user3578166 Yup.. External storage write and read permission.

Comment: i am trying this code and get this error : not such file or dir is exist

Comment: @user3578166 in which function.. ?? while back up or restoration?

Comment: Please, include the code snippet into the answer, as sites may go down and therefore the answer looses the essential information.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. It is work for me. Is there any way to restore backup file by asking (given permission for selection) user run time while restoring shared preference files.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences are deleted when you uninstall an app, so no: SharedPreferences aren't the best option here. I would recommend using some kind of remote database to track the usage of your app.

Comment: Well, I can't supply the total source code for creating a database connection but there is a lot of info to be found on the web about this topic. You can set up a MySQL database and communicate with it using a web service or use a simpler service like Parse.com to make an easy connection to a database.

Answer (score 0):

`Shared Preferences` are always cleared along with uninstalling app. But since **android-21** Backup task stores preferences by default to cloud. Later when you uninstall then install newer version .You are probably going to use restored preferences. You just have to add this to your `manifest` ( or at least manifest for debug). -

```
<application ...
    android:allowBackup="true">
 ...
</application>
```

Read this:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

It's Important to mention here that process of backup is blackbox .. you don't know when it starts, and period between checks ... so better for developing to disable it.